# How to remove an entity when it is used an association class?

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a class user with a one-to-many relationship against `ArticleVote` which is itself an `Association Class` (see below).

Here is how my entities looks like:

```
class User
{
    protected $articlesVotes;
}
```

An user holds an `ArticleVote` collection.

While an ArticleVote is referenced by a composite primary key based on the `UserId` and the `ArticleId`:

```
class ArticleVote
{
    protected $article;
    protected $user;
}
```

Now, let's say I want to remove an `ArticleVote` from `User`, naturally I do `$user->getArticlesVotes()->removeElement($articleVote);` which results in the actual removing of the entity **inside the collection** but as the `ArticleVote` is both a relationship and an entity, the row in database is not removed at all.

I know, I can do `$em->remove($articleVote);` but I wish I could remove it from the collection of the user to bypass the EntityManager, what if I want to remove several `$articleVote`?

Currently, I create/remove the vote in my `User` model by passing the `Article` entity and it's my `User` entity which creates the `ArticleVote` object and append it itself, I wish I could have the same behavior for the removal feature.

Any ideas? (oh, and by the way, I already tried with cascade="remove")

Comment: There is an option called orphanRemoval (see here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) which might work. But you have to make sure you delete the ArticleVote from both the Article and the User Collection.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes, well I'm not sure the orphanRemoval may work here, I'm not deleting the User neither the Article, I'm removing the Association Class between them. By the way, the ArticleVote entity is not inversed by the Article entity.

Comment: Looking at the example, I think it's exactly what you need. You are deleting an object from a collection and want to have it deleted in database also. That's what they do in the example! I am not sure if it works as your object is refered to in both the User and the Article, but I would give it a try!

Comment: @Sgoettschkes, damn you're right, I was misinformed on the behavior of orphanRemoval! Can you post it as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

I ran to this exact issue yesterday. When setting cascade="remove" this removes the association marked within your UnitOfWork. However to have the items removed from the database you need to mark your $user property in the ArticlesVote Entity to cascade on delete. Like so..

```
class ArticleVote
{
    protected $article;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity=....
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

This will add an "on delete" cascade to the foreign key in your database, and article votes associated with a deleted user will be deleted along with it.